# RepositoryItem from List&Label .lst file

Tags: listlabel

Currently we are using a WPF application for creation/editing of List&Label Templates, but we are considering to move to the WebDesigner. Because we use project includes we need to use the repository mode.

I've been trying to import our existing templates, but I run into some issues regarding the `RepositoryItemDescriptor`. To create a `RepositoryItem` object you have to give a `Descriptor` in the constructor, but I cannot find any info regarding how you get it from the generated `.lst` file.

The data that we have at our disposal are:

- TemplateType: List or Form
- TemplateData: content of the `.lst` file (`byte[]`)
- IsMainTemplate: `bool`, is a "project include" or not
- File name: name of the `.lst` file

The `RepositoryItem` constructor requires: `string internalID, string descriptor, string type, DateTime lastModificationUTC`.

What I have now is:

```
public class TemplateBaseModel : RepositoryItem
{
    // Properties

    // we have our own Ids and modification date, override RepositoryItem properties
    public new InternalID => $"repository://{{{Id}}}";
    public DateTime LastModificationUTC => ModifiedOn; 

    public TemplateBaseModel() : base($"repository://{{{Guid.NewGuid()}}}", /* ?? */, RepositoryItemType.ProjectList.Value, DateTime.Now) { }
    public TemplateBaseModel(string internalID, string descriptor, string type, DateTime lastModificationUTC) : base(internalID, descriptor, type, lastModificationUTC) { }
}
```

In the documentation I can only find what it is (internal metadata that is serialized into a string, and can be edited with the class `RepositoryItemDescriptor`), but not how it's created or how you can get it, and if I try to debug the example I get (in the `CreateOrUpdate()` method)`@2@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`, which doesn't help either.

Any idea how to properly create a `RepositoryItem` from a `.lst` file? or how to create/get the `descriptor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and use the class `RepositoryImportUtil` from the `combit.ListLabel23.Repository` namespace. This helper class does all the hard work for you. Given an `IRepository`interface and the lst file in place, the required code would be something like

```
IRepository listLabelRepository = <yourRepository>;

using (ListLabel LL = new ListLabel())
{
    LL.FileRepository = listLabelRepository;
    using (RepositoryImportUtil importUtil = new RepositoryImportUtil(listLabelRepository))
    {
        importUtil.ImportProjectFileWithDependencies(LL, 
            @"<PathToRootProject>");
    }
}
```

If this method is not what your require, the helper class has a couple of [other methods](https://docu.combit.net/net/en/#combit.ListLabel~combit.ListLabel.Repository.RepositoryImportUtil_members.html) as well to help you importing existing projects.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to pass the file as a `byte[]` instead of the file path? or do I have to write the byte array to file, and then pass it to the import util?

Comment: Currently, only a file path is supported. Note that the method automatically patches relative paths to the corresponding repository items, thus you should make sure to have all projects/dependencies at hand. The method is documented at https://docu.combit.net/net/en/#combit.ListLabel~combit.ListLabel.Repository.RepositoryImportUtil~ImportProjectFileWithDependencies.html